# Python - Struct unpack bytes to ascii characters but with accents

Tags: python, struct, ascii, diacritics, unpack

I am trying to unpack some bytes with `struct.unpack()` in Python.

```
struct.unpack("xb4s", b'\x00\x04G\xe9g\xe9')
```

But I get : `(4, b'G\xe9g\xe9')` instead of `(4, Gégé)`. This code does not handle accents. What should I do to have accents ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string was was encoded with [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), so decode it appropriately.

```
In [3]: struct.unpack("xb4s", b'\x00\x04G\xe9g\xe9')[1].decode('cp1252')
Out[3]: 'Gégé'
```